# I want create loop for this jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a loop for this. But I have another loop in to get select value, it takes me var other variables and it seems complex.

> ** After this loop, I want to keep all subtotal variables:

```
sum of

format__1_value format__2_value format__3_value...

or sum array

[format__1_value, format__2_value, format__3_value...]
```

In code, I must var a variable. But when I use "each" to loop this, it can't declare var for loop. How can I declare "var format__1", and loop in "format__2", "format__3" to run small loop in this.?

How could I have a loop for all of this, and not make small loop broken?

I want to take sum of these element values

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#format").on("change", function() {

    var $i = 0;
    var price = 0;

    $("#format").each(function() {

      var format = [];
      $.each($("input[name='format__" + (i + 1) + "']:checked"), function() {
        format.push($(this).val());
      });
      var format_select = format.join(", ");

      if (format_select.includes("SEO") == true) {
        var format_value_seo = 0.5;
      } else {
        var format_value_seo = 0;
      }

      if (format_select.includes("PR") == true) {
        var format_value_pr = 1.5;
      } else {
        var format_value_pr = 0;
      }

      if (format_select.includes("Review") == true) {
        var format_value_review = 2;
      } else {
        var format_value_review = 0;
      }

      var format_value = format_value_seo + format_value_pr + format_value_review;


      // Set price for content


      var basic_price = 12000;


      price += Math.round(basic_price * (1 + format_value));

    });

    $("input[name=price]").val(price);

    return false;

  });
});
```

```html
<div data-wpcf7-group-id="content_details" id="content_details" tabindex="1" class="wpcf7-field-groups ">
  <div class="wpcf7-field-group">
    <table style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:70%;text-transform:none;border-bottom:none">
            <label><b>Tiêu đề bài viết</b><br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap subject__1"><input type="text" name="subject__1" value="Tác giả tự đặt tiêu đề cho bài này" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span></label>
          </th>
          <th style="width:30%;text-transform:none;border-bottom:none">
            <label><b>Độ dài content</b><br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap length__1"><input type="number" name="length__1" value="400" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-number wpcf7-validates-as-number" id="length" aria-invalid="false"></span></label>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap format__1"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="format"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__1[]" value="SEO"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">SEO</span></label>
      </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__1[]" value="PR"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">PR</span></label>
      </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__1[]" value="Review"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Review</span></label>
      </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__1[]" value="Seeding"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Seeding</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p><button type="button" class="wpcf7-field-group-remove " style="display: none;">-</button><button type="button" class="wpcf7-field-group-add ">+</button><input type="hidden" class="wpcf7-field-group-count" name="_wpcf7_groups_count[content_details]__1"
        value="3"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="wpcf7-field-group">
    <table style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:70%;text-transform:none;border-bottom:none">
            <label><b>Tiêu đề bài viết</b><br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap subject__2"><input type="text" name="subject__2" value="Tác giả tự đặt tiêu đề cho bài này" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span></label>
          </th>
          <th style="width:30%;text-transform:none;border-bottom:none">
            <label><b>Độ dài content</b><br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap length__2"><input type="number" name="length__2" value="400" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-number wpcf7-validates-as-number" id="length" aria-invalid="false"></span></label>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap format__2"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="format"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__2[]" value="SEO"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">SEO</span></label>
      </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__2[]" value="PR"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">PR</span></label>
      </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__2[]" value="Review"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Review</span></label>
      </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__2[]" value="Seeding"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Seeding</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p><button type="button" class="wpcf7-field-group-remove ">-</button><button type="button" class="wpcf7-field-group-add ">+</button><input type="hidden" class="wpcf7-field-group-count" name="_wpcf7_groups_count[content_details]__2" value="3"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="wpcf7-field-group">
    <table style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:70%;text-transform:none;border-bottom:none">
            <label><b>Tiêu đề bài viết</b><br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap subject__3"><input type="text" name="subject__3" value="Tác giả tự đặt tiêu đề cho bài này" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span></label>
          </th>
          <th style="width:30%;text-transform:none;border-bottom:none">
            <label><b>Độ dài content</b><br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap length__3"><input type="number" name="length__3" value="400" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-number wpcf7-validates-as-number" id="length" aria-invalid="false"></span></label>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap format__3"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="format"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__3[]" value="SEO"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">SEO</span></label>
      </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__3[]" value="PR"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">PR</span></label>
      </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__3[]" value="Review"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Review</span></label>
      </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__3[]" value="Seeding"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Seeding</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p><button type="button" class="wpcf7-field-group-remove ">-</button><button type="button" class="wpcf7-field-group-add ">+</button><input type="hidden" class="wpcf7-field-group-count" name="_wpcf7_groups_count[content_details]__3" value="3"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: unclear. please mention what it is that you want achieve.

Comment: Yeah, I have edited this question. I need the sum of elements

Comment: even with the edits the question is still unclear.

Comment: In code, I must var a variable. But when I use "each" to loop this, it can't declare var for loop. How can I declare "var format__1", and loop in "format__2", "format__3" to run small loop in this.?

Comment: I want to keep array of loop (question edited)

Comment: Added html to track (question edited)